# Añadir estilo css a elemento haciendo hover a otro elemento

Tags: css, css3

Quiero que cuando se haga hover a `.borrarTema`, el mismo `div` cambie de opacidad a 1 (anteriormente 0.6) y que también haga modificar el `box-shadow` del `div` `.comentario` a `0px 3px red` (anteriormente `0px 3px #4AA184`).

Mi php es el siguiente:

```
<div class='contComentarios'>
    <div class='creadorFecha'>
        <div> Creado por: <strong>". $registro2['Nombre'] ."</strong></div>
                                        <div>". $registro['Fecha'] ."</div>
    </div>

    <div class='comentario'>". $registro['Comentario'] ."</div>

    <div class='borrarTema'>
        <div id=". $registro['IdComentario'] ." class='borraCmnt' value='Borrar comentario'>Borrar tema</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Los estilos son los siguientes:

```
.contComentarios .comentario{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px #4AA184;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 60px;
}

.borrarTema{
    background-color: #4AA184;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -17px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: 0.2s all;
}
```

Comment: sería recomendable que si tu cuestión ha sido resuelta que cierres la pregunta valorando una de las respuestas como correcta con el check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta corta es no, no se puede modificar un elemento al gusto haciendo el `hover` en otro. Sólo se puede si el elemento es adyacente (operador `+`), un hijo del elemento sobre el que haces `hover` (operador `>`) o si ambos están bajo el mismo padre y uno precede al otro (operador `~`). [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/761181) tienes mucha más información.

Una opción que tienes (si no quieres utilizar JS) es reordenar los elementos y que tu `div` de borrar tema esté encima del comentario. Te dejo un ejemplo. De todas formas, lo más lógico sería utilizar JS.

```css
.contComentarios .comentario{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px #4AA184;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 60px;
}

.borrarTema{
    background-color: #4AA184;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -17px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: 0.2s all;
}

.borrarTema:hover{
   opacity: 1;
}

.borrarTema:hover ~ .comentario{
   box-shadow: 0px 3px red;
}
```

```html
<div class='contComentarios'>
<br/>
 <div class='borrarTema'>
        <div id="idborrar" class='borraCmnt' value='Borrar comentario'>Borrar tema</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='creadorFecha'>
        <div> Creado por: <strong>Autor</strong></div>
                                        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div class='comentario'>Este es un comentario</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, utilizaré entonces JS.

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizaria jQuery para hacer estos cambios.

Con el comando `hover` le añades la funcionalidad que buscas, y con el selector `css` vas cambiandoles las propiedades a los elementos que elijas.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.borrarTema).hover(function(){ 
            $(this).css('opacity',1);
            $('.comentario).css('box-shadow','0px 3px red' );
    });
});
```